# Excel: Countif of Countif

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, array-formulas

I'd like to know if there's a way to calculate two countifs with different data and criteria in a single formula (not row by row or with pivot tables). Let the following example apply:

I have the following table: fields A, B and C for each item (ID). Table header starts in cell T1.

[image: Data Table]

I'd like to know how many items have 2 or more fields (A, B, C) with a number greater than 5.

I'd create another column X and use the following formula row by row: (Example for row 2)

```
=COUNTIF(U2:W2;">5")
```

and for that new column X (with all the COUNTIF formulas) I would use another COUNTIF

```
=COUNTIF(X:X;">1)
```

Is there a way to concatenate both? (I guess with an array formula)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
=SUMPRODUCT((((U2:U11>5)+(V2:V11>5)+(W2:W11>5))>1)*1)
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(((U2:U11>5)+(V2:V11>5)+(W2:W11>5))>1))
```

[image]

---

You can also use `SUM(IF())` as an array formula like below

```
=SUM(IF(((U2:U11>5)+(V2:V11>5)+(W2:W11>5))>1, 1, 0))
```

Above being an array formula needs to be committed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.